# PHP Using ssh2_shell() with socket_select()

Tags: php, sockets, ssh

I'm using php to open an ssh session.

e.g.:

```
$stream = ssh2_shell($connection, 'vt102', null, 80, 24, SSH2_TERM_UNIT_CHARS);
```

I can read the stream with:

```
$content=stream_get_contents($stream);
```

In order to monitor the stream I want to connect it to a socket.
So that I can use `socket_select()`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - ssh is a layer of protocol on top of a socket - you can't inject code between the layers) but socket_select operates at the socket layer.

But in PHP there is an additional layer on top of the ssh layer - the stream - and you can use [stream_select()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php) on a set of streams (which can include stuff other than ssh)

Comment: I want to monitor the ssh stream and a socket at the same time - then do something if one of them changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), and then do stream_select($ssh->fsock) or socket_select($ssh->fsock).